# In apps billing signature verification

Tags: android, in-app-billing, developer-payload

I got a question regards on developer payload, I've been reading the document and still finding myself to hard to understand the verifydeveloperpayload I still dont understand about :

```
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
        /*
         * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct. It will be
         * the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
         *
         * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase and
         * verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will fail in the
         * case where the user purchases an item on one device and then uses your app on
         * a different device, because on the other device you will not have access to the
         * random string you originally generated.
         *
         * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
         *
         * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different between them,
         *    so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to another user.
         *
         * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app wasn't the
         *    one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items purchased by the user on
         *    one device work on other devices owned by the user).
         *
         * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across app
         * installations is recommended.
         */
        return true;
    }
```

If my code were

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String item1;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1: {
            /* TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See the comments on
             *        verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is a SAMPLE, we just use
             *        an empty string, but on a production app you should carefully generate this. */

            item1 = "item1";
            String payload = email+item1;

            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_2006, RC_REQUEST,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
            break;
            }
         }
```

}

will the String payload from the boolean verifyDeveloperPayload equal to String payload from my onClick method?

How and where do i compare the payload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html) it is stated that

> The fifth argument contains a ‘developer payload’ string that you can
>   use to send supplemental information about an order (it can be an
>   empty string). Typically, this is used to pass in a string token that
>   uniquely identifies this purchase request. If you specify a string
>   value, Google Play returns this string along with the purchase
>   response. Subsequently, when you make queries about this purchase,
>   Google Play returns this string together with the purchase details.
>
> **Security Recommendation:** It’s good practice to pass in a string that
>   helps your application to identify the user who made the purchase, so
>   that you can later verify that this is a legitimate purchase by that
>   user. For consumable items, you can use a randomly generated string,
>   but for non-consumable items you should use a string that uniquely
>   identifies the user.

So , For the product ID **SKU_2006** if you initiated the purchase flow with `String payload = email+item1;` then Google Play will return the same payload in the response and hence you would get it here as

```
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
..
}
```

Now , let me define the whole scenario in terms of code :

First , you would initiate a purchase request like below

```
String payload = getUserEmailFromAndroidAccounts() + itemUniqueId;

mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(new PurchaseFinishListener(itemUniqueId), SKU_GAS, 10001,   
   mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

If the purchase order is successful, the response data from Google Play is stored in an Purchase object that is passed back to the listener.

```
    private class PurchaseFinishListener implements IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener {
   private final String mItemUniqeId;
    public PurchaseFinishListener(String itemUniqeId) {

            mItemUniqeId = itemUniqeId;
        }

       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
       {
          if (result.isFailure()) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
             return;
          }      
    if (!verifyDeveloperPayLoad(mItemUniqeId , purchase)) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Authenticity verification failed");
             return;
    }

    // set your product as purchased in your DB or server

    }
    }
```

Now your verifyDeveloperPayLoad(purchase) method should look as below :

```
 private boolean verifyDeveloperPayLoad(String itemUniqueId , Purchase purchase) {
        String responsePayload = purchase.getDeveloperPayload();
        String computedPayload = getUserEmailFromAndroidAccounts() + itemUniqueId;

        return responsePayload != null && responsePayload.equals(computedPayload);
    }
```

If you have closely observed code , you would surely understand how is the work flow .

Further information about Subscription based purchase and one time purchase can be obtained from Android site.

Comment: What is an example of `itemUniqueId` in this case, especially in the initial statements? a random string?

Comment: @John61590 I think it's the product ID